# Headline won't stay above table in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, office365

I have a headline above a table, except it won't actually go above the table, just to the previous page. The table won't move: when I press Enter at the beginning of it, it just moves the text inside, not the table itself. When I go to the previous page and press delete, the headline just gets "sucked in" to the first column of the table, it won't stay above. This is in Office 365. Any ideas?

Comment: Insert a page break before the heading.

Comment: It just puts the heading on a new page all on its own, and the table on the next page. The table and the headline are like feuding spouses, they refuse to be together and I don't know how to convince them otherwise.

Comment: Try [keeping paragraphs together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-lines-and-paragraphs-together-d72af534-926f-4c4b-830a-abfc2daa3bfa)

Comment: Try turning off [Keep Lines Together](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T012975_Keeping_Tables_on_One_Page.html) for the table

Comment: Hm, neither turning it on for the headline and the table, nor turning it off for the table, seemed to work, they just stayed right put.

Comment: I've turned "Keep lines together" and "Page break before" off for the table, and "Keep with next" on for the heading.

Comment: [Troubleshooting guide for unwanted page breaks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/233493)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with WORD 2013 and I found the answer in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/wd2013-wont-allow-tables-to-break-across-pages/09c1e14c-4c4e-4913-8261-456cf7500900?page=3:

> Is "Text wrapping" set to "Around" on the Table tab of Table Properties?

After setting the text wrapping from "None" to "Around" it worked fine.

Comment: YES! Finally, it looks so beautiful :'). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I highlighted the table, right click, table properties.  selected the text wrapping option from 'none' to 'around' and then toggled the specific height off.  clicked ok and the tables were perfect.